# Best approach to send props to react application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a use case where I want to open a react application in new window whenever user clicks a button. I want to pass some props to the react application. Presently I am sending the props via appending them to URL.

**Example**
Let's say my application is accessible at lomoto/car. I am currently sending parameters via lomoto/car/value1/value2. I am accessing these properties via props.match.params.prop1 and props.match.params.prop2. I am using react-router v4 for routing.

Is there any other recommended way of achieving this?

Comment: I'd opt for using the query string for this instead :)

Answer (score 1):

You can save the state to the browser's local storage and then access it from any tab.

In this [egg head video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage) Dan Abramov explains how to make use of the browser's local storage for redux.

You can use a similar approach with or without redux.